# No function declarations for operator + error in VHDL

Tags: vhdl

In this piece of code I get this error for the line with +

```
function func (bv1 : in bit_vector; bv2 : in integer) return bit_vector is

    variable temp : natural := 2**bv2;
    variable result : bit_vector(1 to 32);
  begin
    report "asd" & natural'image(temp);
     result <= bv1 + temp; // this line causes the error
    return result;
  end func;
```

The error is :

> No function declarations for operator +

How can I solve this? I also get a similar error for "=" as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because you try to add a `natural` to a `bit_vector` which does not work because they are of different types. So you'll have to use a converter, e.g. as shown [here](http://www.ics.uci.edu/~jmoorkan/vhdlref/vhdl.html) within one of the functions. The other method is to stick to all the same types, but that isn't always possible.

Answer (score 4):

Don't use `bit_vectors` (or `std_logic_vector`s, really) for anything you want to do arithmetic on.

Use the ieee.numeric_std library and then declare your signals (or whatever) to be of type `signed` ot `unsigned` depending on what type of vector you want.   (Or of course, you can just use `integer`s and the subtypes of that)

Answer (score 1):

Some initial problems with the code are that VHDL comments markup is `--`, not
`//`, and assign to `result` variable must use `:=`, since `<=` is for assign
to signal.

Then, the reason for the error:

> No function declarations for operator +

is that VHDL is a strong typed language, so it is not possible just to add a
`natural` type and a `bit_vector` type, as attempted in `result <= bv1 + temp`.
Instead you need to use the package `numeric_bit_unsigned`, and for example
convert `temp` to `bit_vector` using function `to_bitvector` before adding.

Resulting code can then be:

```
library ieee;
use ieee.numeric_bit_unsigned.all;
...
function func (bv1 : in bit_vector; bv2 : in integer) return bit_vector is
  variable temp   : natural := 2**bv2;
  variable result : bit_vector(1 to 32);
begin
  report "asd" & natural'image(temp);
  result := bv1 + to_bitvector(temp, result'length);  -- this line causes the error
  return result;
end func;
```

You should check that the length is enough to handle the required values.

However, instead of using `bit_vector` type, you may consider the
`std_logic_vector` (depending on the design), since the `std_logic_vector` has
additional values that may reveal design problem in simulation.